# Suite crm notification not working

Tags: sugarcrm, suitecrm

I am new to **suite crm** and have successfully set it up and is up and running.

The notification system is not working at all and not showing up any alerts.

***Here is what I have done***

- Succesfully setup suite crm and working well
- Set up cronjobs on server as mentioned on the admin/ sheduler sections
- Repaired scheduler after setting up the scheduler

Tested to see if the  notification works or not by setting up the **renewal reminder date** fields in the **contract module** but the notification is not showing up.

What am I missing or doing wrong. In the admin/scheduler settings I can see the lists of schedulers. How to know which scheduler will serve my purpose. Is it possible to create new scheduler. I cannot see any options to create a new scheduler.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have set properly set permission on server. 755 on all suitecrm files and 777 for cache and custom. After that execute repair and rebuild. Execute any database mismatch query.

After that make sure that "Optimise Advanced OpenDiscovery Index" scheduler is executing without any issue. See following image for reference:

[image]

Comment: I have made the permission changes and When getting into The scheduler Optimise AOD Index . And checking the JOB LOGS is empty.Can't see any notification either after the process

Comment: if job log is empty then your job is not running. It should show some entries there. Have you enabled crontab on your server? your other jobs are executed?